# Get current Visibility Timeout for a message

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm pretty new to SQS and am sorry if I glossed over something obvious but is there a way to get the current visibility timeout for a message in SQS? I can see how to update the timeout visibility [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-sqs-visibility-timeout.html). but I don't see any info on getting the current visibility timeout for a message (perhaps you can view it on receiving the message somehow).

My use-case is changing the visibility timeout based on the current visibility timeout for a given message. Is this possible?

(Note: I'm aware I can use the approximate received time to a similar effect and will go that route if getting the current visibility time is impossible)

Comment: Suspect you will have to get the SQS queue's visibility timeout (use GetQueueAttributes) and extrapolate from the time you called ReceiveMessage.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod , but unfortunately, I plan on changing the visibility timeout on a per message basis so that approach likely won't work

Comment: Why? You know the queue's visibility timeout, you receive some messages, you inherently know the timeout for each message based on those two pieces of information, you then change the visibility timeout on a per-message (or per-batch) basis as needed.

Comment: I want to implement exponential backoff in a similar fashion to something like [this](https://ivan-site.com/2018/06/exponential-backoff-in-sqs/) but ideally these factors will be configurable.

The problem there being that if you change a value, you no longer know to which value you should set the next timeout

Comment: If I understand, could you persist your own mapping of MessageId to timeout in a map (or DynamoDB) for a short period of time?

Comment: @jarmod yup that's totally possible and one of the options I've considered. It would still be nicer if I could get that property from the message but it seems that is not possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this is not possible.

Though the ApproximateReceiveCount is likely to suffice for my use-case at least.

Comment: How did you use `ApproximateReceiveCount` to handle the need of getting `VisibilityTimeout`? Those are totally different things. The former will give you *how many times the message has been received* while you need *for how long is the message not visible by other readers*

Comment: Yes this is true. Fortunately, the `VisibilityTimeout` I set for each message is based on the `ApproximateReceiveCount` and I was able to get a close enough approximation this way. Unfortunately, this does not work as a general solution for other use-cases.